# C arrays memcmp trouble

Tags: c, arrays

I need to write a code for my UNI, in which I have to receive 2 arrays of some data (it may be int array or char array or even float array) and compare n characters from pointers in both of the arrays, so far I am stuck with this
***note in other words - I need to write my own memcmp** :

```
int byte_compare(const void *b1,const void *b2,size_t len)
{
    char *q1 = (char *)p1;
    char *q2 = (char *)p2;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=len*sizeof(*q1) ;i++)
    {
      if(*q1++ != *q2++)
           return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}   

int main()
{
          char str1[] = "abcheya";
          char str2[] = "gtyheyb";

          printf((byte_compare(str1[3],str2[3],3))?"not equal\n":"equal\n");
          /*the output is equal*/

          int arr1[]={1,2,3,4};
          int arr2[]={1,2,7,59};

          printf((byte_compare(arr1[0],arr2[0],3))?"not equal\n":"equal\n");
          /*the output is also equal although it is not supposed to be*/

          return 0;
}
```

when I compare strings it works just fine, but when I try to compare int or float it wont work properly, please help me.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Choose one and only one.

Comment: It's C, but I assume that everyone that knows c++ knows some sort of C, they are the same base

Comment: Are you using passing the correct `len` for ints and floats? it should be `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(float)` respectively

Comment: Define "won't work properly". Do you get an exception? Is the result just wrong? What is the result?

Comment: `memcmp` takes `void*` parameters, why the cast to `char*`? Your whole function could be replaced by `memcmp` as it currently is

Comment: What do you mean by 'it wont work properly' and what is the expected 'proper' work?

Comment: @YaroslavMiloslavsky not necessarily. Plus we need to know if its C or C++, the answers will vary _a lot_ for that type of problem.

Comment: @CiaPan @ Jerome Reinländer
When i compare 2 arrays of chars, it returns 0 as intended.
However when i compare int arrays it will give me 0 even if they are not equal!

Comment: @KarstenKoop our teahcer told us to use casting to char * because it consumes 1 byte

Comment: The code you posted works fine. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit the input and outouts you use to see that it is not working into your question and not in a comment.

Comment: @YaroslavMiloslavsky: `char*` doesn't consume 1 byte, it's a pointer and it has the same width as `void*`.

Comment: @Stargateur thanks edited, first timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: to write own `memcmp` function

```
int byte_compare(const void *b1,const void *b2,size_t len)
{
    if (len != 0) {
        register const unsigned char *p1 = b1, *p2 = b2;

        do {
            if (*p1++ != *p2++)
                return (*--p1 - *--p2);
        } while (--len != 0);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the comparing byte length while passing the len parameter. So, you can use templates for this.

```
template<typename T>
int byte_compare(const T *b1, const T *b2, size_t len)
{
    return memcmp(b1, b2, len * sizeof(T));  
}
```

Edit note : The question is edited and the answer has no more meaning. And it uses C++, not applicable for C lessons. I'm remaining the answer for whose have no restriction to use C++.

Comment: the question is about C, your code is obviously C++, this is not answer the question.

Comment: @Stargateur Yeah, i didn't notice that it was a C homework problem. So, maybe he can pass data length to the method instead of array length. 
I will remain my answer, some other c++ users could search it. Thanks.

Comment: @Y.Doktur It works for C too! thank you very much' can you explain why it works? why didnt memcmp(*b1,*b2,int) worked? i need to compare 'len' chars of 2 given arrays, and your solution works!

Comment: @YaroslavMiloslavsky memcmp's length parameter accepts data length, not array length. It compares the data byte by byte. For example; you have an array of 3 integers and you pass 3 for len, it will compare 3 bytes. But, the data size is 3 * sizeof(int). So, you should calculate the variable type's length while passing memcmp's len parameter.

Comment: @Y.Doktur but if i dont know the type of the data? I would just write sizeof(q1) for example?

Comment: @YaroslavMiloslavsky That's why i used templates:) sizeof(T) will give you the size of the data type which you passed. I don't know if it's a homework or not. And i don't know if you should use the exact method inputs and outputs, but you can solve it by passing the data length to your method while calling it in pure C.

Comment: @Y.Doktur I was wrong about some things, I asked my teacher if i could use memcmp and he said that i have to write my own memcmp, please review my code if you have the time for still it doesnt work properly

Comment: @YaroslavMiloslavsky Here is the implemetation of memcmp. You can use or modify it according to your lesson learned. 
https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-3.1/tcl/compat/memcmp.c

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the *size* of the objects, not their length:

```
int byte_compare(const void *b1, const void *b2, size_t size)
{    
   return memcmp(b1, b2, size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor probably does not want you to use a library call. So write a byte by byte comparison (aka memcmp).

Get a copy of K&R C (or another book on C), and you will find examples of how to process char(acter) values in a loop.

```
int byte_compare(const void *b1,const void *b2,size_t len)
{
    if( !b1 || !b2 ) return 0; //0 represents false
    char* p1=(char*)b1; char* p2=(char*)p2;
    for( ; len --> 0; ) {
        if( *p1++ != *p2++ ) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: this compares only the first byte

Comment: Good catch, fixed.